# In Rails, how can I create a button that saves an entry from an external api into my database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, api, httparty

I have an Rails api that consumes an external design search api using the HTTParty gem. With the data that is returned to my view I'd like to be able to save selected entries to my database. Kind of like a bookmark function. Is there anyway of having a button next to each search result item that would achieve this? Any help would really be appreciated. My current code is below.

designs controller:

```
class DesignsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @search = Api.new.find(params[:q])['results']
    end
end
```

Class method:

```
class Api
  include HTTParty
  base_uri "http://search.example.com/searchv2"

  attr_accessor :name, :limit, :offset

  # Find a particular design, based on its name
  def find(name)
    self.class.get("/designs", query: { q: name }).parsed_response
  end
end
```

View:

```
<h1>Design Search</h1>

<%= form_tag(designs_path, method: :get) do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>

<h2>Search results:</h2>

<% @search.each do |design| %>  
<h3><%= design['name'] %></h3>
<h5><%= image_tag design['thumbnail_url'] %></h5>
<% end %>
```

Design model:

```
class Design < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Comment: What do you use the `Design` model? Because that's the perfect place to put/store the "results" (for each item they clicked). If this is what you intended already but you don't know how to approach this, see my answer below.

Comment: @Jay-Ar Yes, that is what the Design model is intended for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**app/views/designs/index.html.erb:**

```
...
<% @search.each do |design| %>  
  <h3><%= design['name'] %></h3>
  <h5><%= image_tag design['thumbnail_url'] %></h5>
  <%= button_to 'Save',
        designs_path(
          design: design.slice('name', 'thumbnail_url') # etc...
        ),
        method: :post,
        data: { disable_with: 'Loading...' }
  %>
<% end %>
```

**app/config/routes.rb:**

```
resources :designs, only: [:index, :create]
```

**app/controllers/designs_controller.rb:**

```
class DesignsController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def create
    @design = Design.new(design_params)
    @design.save!

    # just an example...
    redirect_to designs_path, success: 'Design has been saved!'
  end

  private

  def design_params
    params.require(:design).permit(:name, :thumbnail_url) # etc...
  end
end
```

### TODOs:

- your `Design` model needs to have attributes that you want to be saved (i.e: `:name`? and `:thumbnail_url`?). My assumption was that you already have created/migrated these attributes; if not yet, then please do add them.
- because there's still a vulnerability in my code above in that any user can modify the `<button>`'s `<form action='...'>` (i.e. they can modify the "name" of the design as they wish when it gets Saved), then my solution above is still not the best solution, though for simplicity and that assuming that this vulnerability is not a problem for you, then the above code already is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer :) Yes, I was looking to do it without AJAX actually :/

 I can't tell if it is saving or not. When i add `@designs = Design.all` to my index action and then go to localhost3000:/designs or try and use the @designs variable in the view there are no saved designs

Comment: @catinahat No prob. I'll update my code to not make use of AJAX :)

Comment: @catinahat I just updated my code. Click the "edited ... ago" above to see what has been changed. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: I'm still not able to view the saved designs... Should i have `attr_accessor :name, :thumbnail_url` in my model?

Comment: @catinahat did you encounter an error? What happens if you click the button? You don't need `attr_accessor` as `:name` and `:thumbnail_url` are already attributes of the `Design` model (my assumption as stated above)

Comment: When i click save it shows loading for a second then nothing happens. No error. What do you mean by "your Design model needs to have attributes that you want to be saved"?

Comment: @catinahat I was already assuming you have `:name` and `:thumbnail_url` attributes / columns in your DB. But this should throw an error, but you said you didn't encounter one. Are you sure you have `@design.save!` and not `@design.save`?

Comment: Yes, i have `@design.save!` and I have those columns in the DB. I ran Design.all in the console and there are some things saved but they all show `<Design id: 1, name: nil, thumbnail_url: nil` etc

Comment: @catinahat Good. Now at least we know, they're being created. Are you using `design.slice('name', 'thumbnail_url')`? it should not be `design.slice(:name, :thumbnail_url)`

Comment: Yes, I'm using `design.slice('name', 'thumbnail_url')`

Comment: @catinahat Can you insert `puts params` just at the start of `def create`? Then, try Save a design again. And then let me know what's been outputted in the terminal.

Comment: `Processing by DesignsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"ESPc/CYIc5xQHGVdnu8/Bz/QgCDCiGmZiAYjtNBNPUWMSXFJw00k/p4aStRBmVyC4k7sxglNs9Qpzyz14OLY6g==", "design"=>{"name"=>"Bobbit Pencil Case", "thumbnail_url"=>"https://s3.amazonaws.com/spoonflower/public/design_thumbnails/0232/9866/rrrrrrrrrrrBobbit_Pencil_Case_v02_shop_thumb.png"}}`

Comment: `{"authenticity_token"=>"ESPc/CYIc5xQHGVdnu8/Bz/QgCDCiGmZiAYjtNBNPUWMSXFJw00k/p4aStRBmVyC4k7sxglNs9Qpzyz14OLY6g==", "design"=>{"name"=>"Bobbit Pencil Case", "thumbnail_url"=>"https://s3.amazonaws.com/spoonflower/public/design_thumbnails/0232/9866/rrrrrrrrrrrBobbit_Pencil_Case_v02_shop_thumb.png"}, "controller"=>"designs", "action"=>"create"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (4.6ms)  INSERT INTO "designs" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2019-01-24 21:59:00.750744"], ["updated_at", "2019-01-24 21:59:00.750744"]]
   (15.1ms)  commit transaction`

Comment: @catinahat Seems like it's working already actually. Can you check `rails console` again. And do `pp Design.order(id: :desc).first`? If there are values already, then it's already working. You already can show these to your pages as you wish.

Comment: ` #<Design id: 10, name: nil, thumbnail_url: nil, created_at: "2019-01-24 21:59:00", updated_at: "2019-01-24 21:59:00">`

Comment: @catinahat hmm something not-normal is going on. Can you `puts design_params` at the start of `def create`? And let me know again what's being outputted.

Comment: what should my routes look like? Before it was:
`Rails.application.routes.draw do
 root 'designs#index'
 resources :designs do
  collection do
   get 'random_search'
  end
 end
end`

Comment: `Processing by DesignsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"cr/JEyMoeUDHBz4k/3O0J8PTlLL+IiwxoHlRk0Pfl5Pv1WSmxm0uIgkBEa0gBdeiHk34VDXn9nwBsF7Sc3ByPA==", "design"=>{"name"=>"2019 Calendar Tea Towel", "thumbnail_url"=>"https://s3.amazonaws.com/spoonflower/public/design_thumbnails/0796/0454/rFloralTeaTowel2018-6_shop_thumb.png"}}
{"name"=>"2019 Calendar Tea Towel", "thumbnail_url"=>"https://s3.amazonaws.com/spoonflower/public/design_thumbnails/0796/0454/rFloralTeaTowel2018-6_shop_thumb.png"}`

Comment: `(0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (3.1ms)  INSERT INTO "designs" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2019-01-24 22:13:26.008600"], ["updated_at", "2019-01-24 22:13:26.008600"]]
   (5.4ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/designs
Completed 302 Found in 41ms (ActiveRecord: 11.0ms)


Started GET "/designs" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-24 23:13:26 +0100
Processing by DesignsController#index as HTML
  Rendering designs/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered designs/index.html.erb within layouts/application (26.6ms)`

Comment: @catinahat the `design_params` looks good either. Hmm, maybe something's wrong with your `Design` model. Is your `Design` model completely empty? or if it has contents, can you show them to me thanks.

Comment: @catinahat Ok. While you're at it. Can you go into `rails console`, and do the following? `design = Design.create(name: 'test1', thumbnail_url: 'test2'); design.reload; pp design` (and let me know what's being outputted)

Comment: Ah, it is working now! I had left the attr_accessor in the model by mistake :/ Thanks so much for helping me through this. It was a real help! :)